# PHP- pages that contain session variables must be linked?

Tags: php

i have a php snippet saying: if this session variable is this, change the header location to this.

the session variables arent working, however.

must the pages be linked?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `username` WHERE `password` = '$pword' AND `username` = '$uname'");
$exsists = 0;

    WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $exsists = 1;
     break;
     }
        if ($exsists){
        $_SESSION['usern23']=$uname;
        $_SESSION['logged']=1;
        header('Location: logged2.php');

                }
```

$_SESSION['usern'] wont show up on logged2.php

Comment: Please show some code. Is the header location on the same domain?

Comment: Can you paste your code here please?

Comment: Do you have session_start() called just before your query for example? And on logged2.php try <?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['usern23']; ?>

Comment: not right before but it's at the top of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they do not have to be linked, but you need to have `session_start()` at the top of your code on both pages.

Take a look at the [documentation to read about session_start()](http://pt.php.net/session_start)

Also:

After the `header('Location: logged2.php');` nothing else should be executed. When your script reaches that line, it will redirect you and you will never see the message you have next.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `session_write_close();` to save a session before doing a redirect.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php